# Production of electric field

Tags: electromagnetism, soft-question

How does varying magnetic field produce an electric field?
Is it a natural phenomenon having no reason? i want the process/steps of producing of an electric field by a varying magnetic field.

Comment: I've seen "plz" a few times already (yes, it's rude), but abbreviating "answer" to "ans." is a new to me...

Comment: ae @JanDvorak..

Comment: What kind of answer do you seek when you ask for a *reason* that this happens..?

Comment: the reason of producing electric field by varying magnetic field @jabirali

Comment: @SHYAMANANDANINGOMBAM jabirali asks what you mean with "reason".

Comment: process/steps of producing of an electric field by a varying magnetic field.@Bernhard

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't an answer to your question because a varying magnetic field doesn't really produce an electric field (and a varying electric field doesn't really produce a magnetic field). Time varying magnetic and electric fields are associated, but it is misleading to imagine that one causes the other.

Even physicists tend to instinctively think of electric and magnetic fields as separate things, but they aren't. Since [Maxwell formulated his equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_equations) in 1862 we have known that they are both aspects of the electromagnetic field. An electromagnetic field can be separated into an electric part and a magnetic part, but this separation is observer dependant. By this I mean that different observers, e.g. observers moving at different velocities, will disagree about the relative magnitudes of the electric and magnetic fields. To get round this, these days we use an [electromagnetic vector potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_four-potential) that includes both the electric and magnetic components. This potential is the same for all observers so its interpretation is unambiguous.

Comment: sir i can get ur ans. but i  found one sentence at  a book of nuclear physics saying that "VARYING MAGNETIC FIELD CAN ACCELERATE CHARGE PARTICLES" and When i searched for the reason of accelearting charge particles by varying magnetic field, i got the answer as, VARYING MAGNETIC FIELD PRODUCES AN ELECTRIC FIELD SO IT CAN ACCELERATE CHARGE PARTICLES. sir so my confusion is herE @JOHN RENNIE

Comment: @SHYAMANANDANINGOMBAM: it's a common shorthand to say *a varying magnetic field produces an electric field*, and we're probably all guilty of saying this at some time. However it is a misrepresentation of the real physics.

Comment: thankz sir... and sir plz tel me why does VARYING MAGNETIC FIELD CAN ACCELERATE CHARGE PARTICLES? while it is said that magnetic field does not any work to a charge particle,so it can`t accelerate charge particle.bd varying magnetic field can accelerate carge particles.@ JOHN RENNIE